# Terminal timing out with wget

Tags: terminal

I am using Terminal to `wget` images from a list of urls in a text file, using the command: `wget -i septweetsimages.csv`.

When the operation hits url and can't connect to its server, Terminal continues in an infinite loop to try to connect, prompting the following result:

```
"Connecting to wtim.es (wtim.es)|69.58.188.49|:80... failed: Operation timed out.
Retrying."
```

How can I get the process to continue on to the next url in the list after say 2 failed connections?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) Can I ask you to [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/332678/edit) your question to include the actual syntax of the command you're using to perform the operation? Without that it's hard to know what you're already trying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please run "man wget" in Terminal and view the description for the option "--tries". Example shown includes "--tries=10".

Answer (score 3):

Below is an example syntax for how you can manage this:

```
wget --tries 10 --waitretry=30 -—wait=20 --random-wait -—referer="" -i septweetsimages.csv
```

In the above syntax, if wget encounters a failure, it'll retry 10 times with a waiting period between each attempt of 30 seconds. It also waits up to 20 seconds before downloading each new image.

Using the `man wget` command in terminal will provide a description of many other options you can use to manage bandwidth, capture a log file, etc.